# Is there a way to prevent Spring Boot from setting Java System Properties on traditional Tomcat deployment?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to deploy a Spring Boot application into a Tomcat 7 server with a very restrictive security policy (`catalina.policy`) which I cannot change.

The problem I am facing is that Spring Boot tries to set a bunch of non-allowed system properties on startup. This prevents Tomcat from starting up in security mode due to security policy errors due to lack of `write` permissions for `java.util.PropertyPermission`. One example of error as it shows in the `catalina.out` log is:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/kerberos- authenticator]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:156)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:145)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied      ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.awt.headless" "write")
at     java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372  )
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:783)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.configureHeadlessProperty(SpringApplication.java:372)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 14 more
```

I followed the instructions about traditional deployment in the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the time of writing, there's no way to configure Spring Boot to stop it from trying to set `java.awt.headless`. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5115) so that we can see about making this possible in a future release.

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming it is a current issue. To clarify, it is not only that System property, there are much more. Do you want me to get a comprehensive list? Can I kindly ask for an upvote if this is actually useful as I am trying to get rid of an answering ban. Thanks again. Will follow up.

Comment: I imagine we'll look at all calls to `System.setProperty` but a comprehensive list of those that are causing you a problem would certainly be useful. If you have such as list, could you please add it to the issue that I opened?

Comment: It is a trial and error process in my case using this security policy: I add the offending property as allowed, restart Tomcat, see new failure, add it, repeat. This way I can compile a list of properties, but this is going to be specific to this security policy, is that still useful?

Comment: A little bit, but it sounds like it'll take you a while to compile the list. It'll probably be easier if we just look at everywhere that we call `System.setProperty`

Comment: That sounds good @AndyWilkinson. Once you have that list I can compare it with my security policy as a test. Unfortunately I cannot share that security policy file due to NDA with the customer.